# Function only when key is pressed?

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>
</form>
```

```
if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
    execute();
    $test = NULL;
 }
 else {
    $test = NULL;
 }
```

I have a normal PHP script that executes a function every time the button is pressed.
As I understood it, it just checks if the variable is not NULL and if the request already happened.

But that's why every time you reload the page the function is executed again. I already tried to set the variable back to NULL after the button click but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-input-element) and [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-br-element)  tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oh that's actually very simple :). You see, once you click on the button, `test` in the `$_POST` array is set to the value of the button (`RUN`). When you reload the page, the input in `$_POST` remains the same. What you have to do is remove the `test` value once you execute it for the first time. Let me show you:

```
if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
    execute();
    unset($_POST['test']);
}
```

The else statement and setting `$test` to `NULL` is not even needed here for what you're trying to achieve, however if you needed them for anything else, the whole point to keep it working is just to keep the first 2 lines in the `if`.

Comment: thank you very much struggeling so long for this thankss

Comment: _"When you reload the page, the input in $_POST remains the same."_ - when you reload the page, the browser makes a new request, sending the same POST data again - and PHP will _populate_ $_POST for the currently running script instance from that. Trying to unset an entry in $_POST makes no sense in that scenario to begin with - $_POST does not survive across multiple requests, it is created new every time.